# Como eu faço para o crontab rodar um shellscript?

Tags: linux, cron

Galera tenho um .sh e estou com dificuldade de fazer ele ser executado no crontab a cada minuto

Exemplo eu tenho meu arquivo .sh /var/www/exec/checarservidor.sh ele está com devidas permissões.

adiciono ele no crontab

```
* * * * *  /var/www/html/exec/checarservidor.sh | sendmail -s "crontab rodado" alexandre@200horas.com.br
```

ele não funciona já tentei também

```
* * * * *  /bin/bash /var/www/html/exec/checarservidor.sh | sendmail -s "crontab rodado" alexandre@200horas.com.br
```

também não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem tente o comando `sh` pois acredito que seja melhor para esse propósito do que o `bash`. Para ter certeza que o seu caminho é exatamente esse use o comando `which` para descobrir *(ou se quiser mais infos use `whereis`)*:

```
which sh
whereis sh
```

Ficando mais ou menos assim no final:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/html/exec/checarservidor.sh | sendmail -s "crontab rodado" alexandre@200horas.com.br
```

Outro detalhes são ... você adicionou na 1º linha de seu arquivo '.sh' o comando de execução? Pois alguns servidores não rodam o arquivo sem isso.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Você esta usando caminhos absolutos dentro do seu arquivo '.sh'? Pois o `crontab` não sabe trabalhar com caminhos relativos e por fim realmente deu permissão com `chmod 777 /var/www/html/exec/checarservidor.sh` ou `chmod +x /var/www/html/exec/checarservidor.sh` para seu arquivo?

Comment: Funcionou!! Obrigado! s2s2